# Rayleigh Quotient of symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with $\operatorname{diag}(xx^T)=\mathbf{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

It is a pratical problem when I want to recover a unit modulus vector from the problem, a more genenral form is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\mathbf{X}}~ &\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{AX})\\
\text{s.t.}~&\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{X}) =\boldsymbol{1}_N\\
~&\mathbf{X}\succeq0,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$.
Or
$$
\begin{aligned}
\max_{\boldsymbol{x}}&~ \frac{\boldsymbol{x}^*\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol{x}}
{\boldsymbol{x}^*\boldsymbol{x}}\\
\text{s.t.}&~\operatorname{diag}({\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^*}) =\boldsymbol{1}_N
\end{aligned}
$$
Compared with standard Rayleigh Quotient, the only difference is the unit vector constraint,
but it is still a convex problem. It is hard for me to obtain a close form solution as standard RQ.

Comment: Hint: If you mean by $1_N$ the unit matrix, (not the matrix with all its entries equalto $1$), $\operatorname{diag}({\boldsymbol{x}\boldsymbol{x}^*}) =\boldsymbol{1}_N$ means that $x=(e^{ia_1},\cdots e^{ia_N})^T$

Comment: I think $1_N$ would be the vector of ones.

Comment: sorry for misinformation, the operator $\operatorname{diag}(\cdot)$ means the vector diagonal elements. And yes, just as your explanation.